# How to call python script in batch file

Tags: python, batch-file

I have a python script which take in 1 input and process to output.
However, when i use batch file to call it like following, it failed to process...

```
cd \
cd ABC
cd input

for %%f in (*.txt) do (
    echo "%%~nf"
    "C:\Python32\python.exe" "D:\ABC\deployment code\add_null.py" "%%~nf.txt"  "%%~nf_processed.txt"
)
```

Anyone know the problem?

Comment: What is the error message you get? What does your echo statement output?

Comment: my batch filename is python.bat
the error is python.bat is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Comment: Are you sure the filename is called `python.bat`? O_o

Answer (score 0):

The batch file itself looks fine. Judging from your error message, make sure that you're in the correct directory when calling the batch file or don't have any typos in its name.